# How to get the "Save in Google Docs" Option when viewing an attachment?

Tags: gmail, google-drive, google-chrome

Using Google Chrome on two computers, two google accounts. I can click "View" next to an attachment within an email, the document will show in a new Google Drive tab with an option to "Save to Google Docs." My co-worker tries opening the same document by clicking view and it opens in a new tab but there isn't an option for saving it to Google docs, just to print or save it to the computer.

The only difference between our two Google accounts is that I have Drive installed on my computer and she does not. BUT I have not been using my Google Drive and it was set to not sync.

We are using the same browser- Google Chrome Version 23.0.1271.64 m, all updates installed. Both trying to view a PDF from an email that I sent her (mine works, hers does not).

I've looked through other feeds here and can't seem to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely this was functionality that Google was rolling out gradually and your co-worker simply hadn't gotten it yet. This is very typical of how Google implements new functions, I expect so that they can halt the deployment if it's found to have an egregious bug and minimize the damage.

Generally, the only thing that can be done is to wait for the rollout to complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the following Google Chrome Extension : [Gmail Attachments To Drive](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail-attachments-to-driv/epoohehjbaenldfbahgcegdmlogakgin)

Comment: The OP has not asked for extension recommendations. Perhaps you should rephrase your answer, or make it a comment, that the OP checks which extensions are installed at his and his co-worker's browsers.

Answer (score 0):

At least with my school Google Drive, in order to save to Drive you would have to click the "open in new tab" button in the top right. After that, the drive symbol with the plus sign pops up and then you can organize you file from there.